# Set array of labels value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I use `FOR` to set label's value from an array of input values but got
error `"Uncaught TypeError: labelArray[i].html is not a function"` .

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  var inputArray = $("input[type=hidden]");
  var labelArray = $(".labels");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    labelArray[i].html(inputArray[i].value);
  }
}
```

But I can do it well one by one like

```
var label = $("#label1");
label.html(inputArray[i].value);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".labels")[0]` is a DOM object,so you should cast it to a jquery obj again
 `$(labelArray[i]).html(inputArray[i].value);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) function which will allows you to always consider the value passed in as an Array and you will have access to an index like this

```
Array.from(inputArray).forEach((currentInputItem, index) => {
     labelArray[index].html(currentInput.value);
});
```

In this example I presume both `labels` and `inputArray` have the same length